# Kotlin intent.putExtra for Serializable gives compilation error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I'm trying to pass a Serializable data class from one activity to another via intent, but Android Studio doesn't accept my data class as an argument. The editor says "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied". If I try to cast my data class to Serializable, it says "this cast can never succeed".
My data class:

```
    @Serializable
data class MessageModel(
    val timeStamp: String,
    val body: String
)
```

And code for passing the extra to the intent:

```
    val intent = Intent(this, MessageActivity::class.java)
    val test = MessageModel("timeStamp", "message body")
    intent.putExtra("A string for referencing", test)
    startActivity(intent)
```

Second method I tried:

```
val intent = Intent(this, MessageActivity::class.java)
val test = MessageModel("timeStamp", "message body")
intent.putExtra("A string for referencing", test as Serializable)
startActivity(intent)
```

I've tried building from the terminal with gradle in case it was Android Studio acting up, but the same problem occurs.

Note: passing string extras works fine, it's just some problem with Serializable.
I don't see what I'm doing wrong, every tutorial and thread I can find simply pass a Serializable object and it works.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You should implement [Serializeable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), not annotate.

data class MessageModel(
val timeStamp: String,
val body: String
): Serializable

Comment: Cheers! I was instructed that the problem was also that my data class uses kotlinx.serialization while putExtra needs java.io.serialization.

Comment: I am using same model for datastore and passing it via intent too.. Now should we not use kotlinx serialization? @IOOFv

Answer (score 2):

One way to overcome this problem and still use Kotlin serializable is to use JSON encoding.

On the sending side, encode as follows

```
intent.putExtra("data", Json.encodeToString(object))
```

On the receiving side, decode as follows

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    val data = intent.getStringExtra("data")
    val object = Json.decodeFromString<Object>(data)
}
```

Comment: I think you're confusing Serializable which is [part of Java/JVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) and [kotlinx.serialization](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html) which is Kotlin-only

Comment: @SergeiKozelko the problem that the OP mentioned is that a Serializable data class using 
kotlinx.serialization can't be passed as an intent extra since the intent is only able to take in serializable objects of the java.io.serialization. That is true.

What I mentioned is that an alternative to converting your data classes to use java.io.serialization is to encode your kotlinx.serialization objects as JSON Strings. And then pass them into intent extras.